# Postgres query for sequence containing camel case

Tags: postgresql

I want to set a sequence in my table. So I listed all sequences with

```
SELECT c.relname 
FROM pg_class c 
WHERE c.relkind = 'S';
```

which gives me e.g.: `tableName_id_seq`

when I try to set the sequence using

```
SELECT setval("tableName_id_seq", (SELECT MAX(id) from "tableName"));
```

I get:

```
ERROR:  relation "tableName_id_seq" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT setval('tableName_id_seq', (SELECT MAX(id) from "t...
```

I already tried single and double quotes. Anyone any idea what to do here?

Comment: cant you use pgadmin?

Comment: Another good example why avoiding quoted identifiers is a good thing. `select ('"tableName_id_seq"', ...)` should work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Avoid creating identifiers in camel case. It's really boring to work with it:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE "CamelCaseSeq";
SELECT nextval(format('%I', 'CamelCaseSeq'));
SELECT setval(format('%I', 'CamelCaseSeq'), 6666);
SELECT currval(format('%I', 'CamelCaseSeq'));
SELECT * FROM "CamelCaseSeq";
```

A quote from the docs:

> Quoting an identifier also makes it case-sensitive, whereas unquoted
>   names are always folded to lower case. For example, the identifiers
>   FOO, foo, and "foo" are considered the same by PostgreSQL, but "Foo"
>   and "FOO" are different from these three and each other.

More info [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) and [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT).